# jQuery click fallback sans hover ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, click, hover

I want to have a function called when you hover over something (and un-hover). However, I also want it to be accessible to ipad(etc.) users who don't have hover. So I want a click fallback to be possible. How do I achieve that? Note that I don't want people to be able to click on it if the hover is working. This is what I have so far, which is pretty close:

```
var collapsed=1, noHover=false;
$('#deeper').hover(function() {deeper();});
$('#deeper').click(function() {if (collapsed || noHover) {
  deeper();
  noHover=true;
}});
function deeper() {
  if (collapsed == 1) {
    collapsed = 0;
    $(this).children().show();
  } else {
    collapsed = 1;
    $(this).children().hide();
  }
}
```

However, this fails - if at page-load you have the mouse hovering over #deeper and you click before moving the mouse (mouse movement seems to be required for .hover to fire), noHover becomes true, making clicks possible, as well as hovers.

There must a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for those. I actually solved my own problem by adding more to the .hover event:
 $('#deeper').hover(function() {noHover=false;vbg = 1;deeperEd();},function() {noHover=false;vbg = 0;deeperEd();});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPad triggers touch events when tapped. One option is to use those instead of click, and don't propagate to the click event (or use a global variable to track click/touch state)

touch works much like click. See this article for more:
http://htmlpad.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/tracking-touch-events-on-the-ipad/

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the jQuery [Touchable/Hoverable plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Hoverable), which unifies touch and mouse events (touchable) and hover events (hoverable) over different platforms like desktops and mobile devices with touchscreens.